# How to handle the case where the element copied by std::copy might be outside of the vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of undetermined length, `vSignal`.

I need to copy a part of `vSignal` into my dictionnary vector:

```
std::copy(vSignalIt1-n1, vSignalIt1, vDictionnary.begin());
```

`vSignalIt1` is one of `vSignal` iterator.
My isssue is that, when I call the `copy()` function, I'm not sure if `vSignalIt1-n1` is pointing a value inside my vector.

I thought about doing a loop with a reverse iterator which would copy the value one by one until I reach the `rend()` of `vSignal` (in fact I did it and it worked).

But is there an alternative solution using the `copy()` function ?

**EDIT:**

A little precision: vDictionnary as a fixed size (n1) and in the case where I can't copy enough value from vSignal to fill it entirely, I complete it with 0.

Comment: Why not just check to see `if (n1 <= vSignalIt1 - vSignal.begin())`?

Comment: I still need to copy values from vSignal into vDictionnary even in this case.

Comment: `std::min(n1, std::distance(vSignal.begin(), vSignalIt1))` ?

Comment: Yes, good idea @Jarod42. It seems obvious now. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
const auto n2 = std::min(n1, std::distance(vSignal.begin(), vSignalIt1));

std::copy(vSignalIt1 - n2, vSignalIt1, vDictionnary.begin());
std::fill(vDictionnary.begin() + n2, vDictionnary.end(), 0);
```